# How to get the Full name to be sorted from the outlook type email address

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have below e-mail address from which i want names only like `Abrar Ahmad` and just remove or ignore email address getting printed.

```
Abrar Ahmad <abrar.ahmad@example.com>; Andre Geurts <andre.geurts@example.com>; Andrzej Kamionek <andrzej.kamionek@example.com>
```

I have tried below but did not get the desired.

```
$ awk '{ gsub( /<>/ , "" ) ;  print $1,$2  }' email
Abrar Ahmad
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/<[^<]*>/,"")}1' file
Abrar Ahmad ; Andre Geurts ; Andrzej Kamionek
```

Comment: Thanks James .. can we also replace `;` to ` ,'.

Comment: Use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=","}{gsub(/<[^<]*>/,"");$1=$1}1' file` for that.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ <.*/,"",$i)}} 1'  Input_file
```

OR to make comma as a output separator try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ <.*/,"",$i)}} 1'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** OR try with `split`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,array,"<");$i=array[1]}} 1' Input_file
```

To make `,` as output separator try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,array,"<");$i=array[1]}} 1'  Input_file
```